# Vertically aligning selected div

Tags: html, css

Currently, my div content is in horizontal style, I want to make the another div content to be position vertically. For my case i want to vertically align my `content1` element

[image: This] This is how i want the css to look like

This is my html code:

```
<div id="binder">
    <div id="content"> 
        <div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="map">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content1">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
 </div>
```

This the css code:

```
#binder{
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}

#content{
font:14px Calibri;
border:1px solid #3EA99F;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
margin:20px;
padding:20px;
}

#sideBar{
border:1px solid #3EA99F;
width:450px;
margin:20px;
padding:30px;
background:#3EA99F;
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually you can do it without using flexbox too.

Code example:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.content-wrapper,
#sidebar{
  float: left;
}

.content-wrapper{
  width:70%;
}

#content,
#content1,
#sidebar {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="binder">
  <div class="content-wrapper">

  <div id="content">
    <div>
      <h1>Content div</h1>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <h3>
      Content1 div
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <h3>
      Sidebar div
    </h3>
</div>
</div>
```

**Notes**

- I added a `.container-wrapper` div as parent of both #content and #content1
- I placed `.container-wrapper` and `#sidebar` next to each other with `float:left`
- In this case the height of the containers is set automatically based on their content, but if you want you can specify a fixed value adding a `height:..px` to the corresponding class/id

Comment: pls take a look at the question again

Comment: @anonymous5671 edited my answer, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
#binder{
 display:-webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
```

to

```
#binder{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

as the explanation is not much enough, please check the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsa3du93/) and please explain if it is not as you expected

EDIT:

Thank you for providing the images.

change the html into

```
<div id="binder">
 <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div id="content"> 
      <div>
          <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div id="map">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
  CONTENT 1
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="sidebar">
  SIDEBAR
 </div>
```

change the css to

```
#binder{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.content-wrapper{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
#sidebar{
 font:14px Calibri;
 border:1px solid #3EA99F;
 -webkit-box-flex:1;
 margin:20px;
 padding:20px;
}
```

check the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsa3du93/1/) for more

Comment: pls take a look at my html code again... Actually i want the #content to be at left and #sidebar at left too except the #content1 should be below of the #content. do you get my idea

Comment: You should rephrase your question. It doesn't explain much.

Comment: @MuhammadAli pls check my question again